# Running a interactive command as a background process in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, background-process

I am facing an issue when I am trying to run a interactive command/app in the background of the shell script. I am trying to log the output of the command to a file. But I don't see that command logging anything to the file. Even executing the command in the bash also did not work as it gets suspended.

Sample script

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
./a.out > test &
PID=$!
sleep 20
kill -9 $PID
done
```

```
[@myprog]$ ./a.out &
[1] 3275
Program started

[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
[@myprog]$
```

Comment: you cannot interact with a background process so why do you want to run it in background?

Comment: @pynexj I am trying to capture the output of that process by redirecting it to file.

Comment: How do you expect to interact with a program, when moved to the background. It is not possible. If you want to log your output in a file and still see the information on the screen, pipe the output to `tee`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a background process to redirect data. You can do the following, which will create a logfile `actions.log` which holds your every action.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

while read -p "action " act; do
        echo $act
done > actions.log
exit 0
```

For you, this would be something like:

```sh
$ a.out > test.log
```

If you do want to have a background process, but need to input data:

```sh
$ function inter_child {
    ./inter.sh  <<-EOF
a
b
c
d
EOF
sleep 10
}
$ inter_child &
$ wait
$ cat actions.log 
a
b
c
d
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please be more specific why you need to create a child process and what's `a.out` is expecting. Hope this helps!

EDIT:
stdout and stderr are two different redirections.
Write stderr to file `2>`: `$ ./a.out 2> error.log`
Redirect stderr to stdout `2>&1`: `$ ./a.out > log.log 2>&1`